# Why does UnkeyedDecodingContainer require an additional outer array when decoding?

Tags: json, swift, codable, decodable

I'm attempting to decode regular expressions from a json file:

```
{
    ...
    "expressions" : [
        {"plus": [1, 2]},
        {"less": [{"plus": [3, 4]}, 5]}
    ],
    ...
}
```

I've aimed for this syntax in order to allow them to be input as clearly as possible.

Initially I used 2 keyed enums, 1 called expressionDesc, which can be a float(.f1), constant(.cnst), or operation(.op). The operation key's associated value is of type operatorDesc which is the second enum. This contains the operator name along with an array of expressions for its parameters:

Using keyed enums meant I had to enter the json like this:

```
{
    ...
    "expressions" : [
        {"op": {"plus": [{"f1":1}, {"f1":2}]}},
        {"op": {"less": [{"op": {"plus": [{"f1":3}, {"f1":4}]}}, {"f1":5}]}}
    ],
    ...
}
```

Which is a lot harder to read, so I attempted to using the UnkeyedDecodingContainer to avoid typing the expression type key, and to then decode based only on the given type of the expression:

```
enum operatorDesc : Decodable {
    case plus([expressionDesc])
    case less([expressionDesc])

    enum key: CodingKey { case plus; case less}
    enum CodingError: Error { case unknownFunction }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: key.self)
        do { let rawValue = try container.decode([expressionDesc].self, forKey: .plus); self = .plus(rawValue); print("Decoded \(self)") }
        catch { do { let rawValue = try container.decode([expressionDesc].self, forKey: .less); self = .less(rawValue); print("Decoded \(self)") }
                catch { throw CodingError.unknownFunction } }
    }
}

indirect enum expressionDesc : Decodable {
    case f1(f1)
    case const(String)
    case op(operatorDesc)
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        var container = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()
        do { let rawValue = try container.decode(Float.self); self = .f1(rawValue); print("Decoded \(self)") }
        catch { do { let rawValue = try container.decode(String.self); self = .const(rawValue); print("Decoded \(self)") }
                catch { do { let rawValue = try container.decode(operatorDesc.self); self = .op(rawValue); print("Decoded \(self)") }
                        catch {self = .f1(999); print("No expression found!") } } }
    }
}

struct sceneDesc : Decodable {
    ...
    let expressions : [expressionDesc]?
    ...
}
```

Unfortunately for some reason this didn't quite give the decoding I expected and threw "expected array and got ..." errors when I tried to enter the expressions as the top json format. However I added additional arrays around the expressions:

```
{
    ...
    "expressions" : [
        [{"plus": [[1], [2]]}],
        [{"less": [[{"plus": [[3], [4]]}], [5]]}]
    ],
    ...
}
```

And this does decode correctly, outputting:

```
Decoded f1(1.0)
Decoded f1(2.0)
Decoded plus([Mobius.expressionDesc.f1(1.0), Mobius.expressionDesc.f1(2.0)])
Decoded op(Mobius.operatorDesc.plus([Mobius.expressionDesc.f1(1.0), Mobius.expressionDesc.f1(2.0)]))
Decoded f1(3.0)
Decoded f1(4.0)
Decoded plus([Mobius.expressionDesc.f1(3.0), Mobius.expressionDesc.f1(4.0)])
Decoded op(Mobius.operatorDesc.plus([Mobius.expressionDesc.f1(3.0), Mobius.expressionDesc.f1(4.0)]))
Decoded f1(5.0)
Decoded less([Mobius.expressionDesc.op(Mobius.operatorDesc.plus([Mobius.expressionDesc.f1(3.0), Mobius.expressionDesc.f1(4.0)])), Mobius.expressionDesc.f1(5.0)])
Decoded op(Mobius.operatorDesc.less([Mobius.expressionDesc.op(Mobius.operatorDesc.plus([Mobius.expressionDesc.f1(3.0), Mobius.expressionDesc.f1(4.0)])), Mobius.expressionDesc.f1(5.0)]))
```

and final expressions constructed are:

```
Mobius.expressionDesc.op(Mobius.operatorDesc.plus([Mobius.expressionDesc.f1(1.0), Mobius.expressionDesc.f1(2.0)]))

Mobius.expressionDesc.op(Mobius.operatorDesc.less([Mobius.expressionDesc.op(Mobius.operatorDesc.plus([Mobius.expressionDesc.f1(3.0), Mobius.expressionDesc.f1(4.0)])), Mobius.expressionDesc.f1(5.0)]))
```

Which are correct.

What I'm wondering is, is there any way to avoid the additional array [] needed around each expression in the json to allow it to decode? (These seem to have appeared only with the use of UnkeyedDecodingContainer in the expression enum)

Also, if anyone knows of a better way to achieve what I'm attempting I'm all ears - the nested do-catches are going to become extremely ugly when I add more operations and from what I've read there's no easy way around this.

Comment: Haha the rest of the project isn't that gritty I swear.. The problem with structs with optionals is that it allows multiple values to be given and also no value to be given, whereas in this case I want it to allow either plus or less, and either float or constant or operation. You're right though it's not pleasant, and god knows how I'm gonna execute them once they're decoded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `decoder.unkeyedContainer` is intended for parsing of arrays. Respectively it's necessary to use `decode.singleValueContainer` for single values:

```
indirect enum expressionDesc : Decodable {
    case f1(f1)
    case const(String)
    case op(operatorDesc)
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        do { let rawValue = try container.decode(Float.self); self = .f1(rawValue); print("Decoded \(self)") }
        catch { do { let rawValue = try container.decode(String.self); self = .const(rawValue); print("Decoded \(self)") }
                catch { do { let rawValue = try container.decode(operatorDesc.self); self = .op(rawValue); print("Decoded \(self)") }
                        catch {self = .f1(999); print("No expression found!") } } }
    }
}
```

I tried your code and parsed first json and it works well:

```
let text = """
{
    "expressions" : [
        {"plus": [1, 2]},
        {"less": [{"plus": [3, 4]}, 5]}
    ]
}
"""

print(try! JSONDecoder().decode(sceneDesc.self, from: text.data(using: .utf8)!))
```

Result:

> sceneDesc(expressions:
>   Optional([testapp.expressionDesc.op(testapp.operatorDesc.plus([testapp.expressionDesc.f1(1.0),
>   testapp.expressionDesc.f1(2.0)])),
>   testapp.expressionDesc.op(testapp.operatorDesc.less([testapp.expressionDesc.op(testapp.operatorDesc.plus([testapp.expressionDesc.f1(3.0),
>   testapp.expressionDesc.f1(4.0)])),
>   testapp.expressionDesc.f1(5.0)]))]))